# IIS 6 App Pools and Windows Services Won't Start

Tags: iis, iis-6, windows-service, windows-server-2003-r2

Windows Server 2003 R2 (x86) / IIS 6.

I'm setting up an ASP.NET application as well as a few windows services that run under "MyServiceAccount". I'm unable, however, to get the app pool nor the window services to start.

The MyServiceAccount is in IIS_WPG, has the appropriate local policy rights and NTFS permissions, and I've even tried granting it local admin.

The app pool fails repeatedly and is stopped automatically by IIS. The error I see in the system event log is:

> A process serving application pool 'MyAppPool' terminated
>   unexpectedly. The process id was '7976'. The process exit code was
>   '0x80'.

The window services fail immediately upon the start request, and the error logged is:

> Timeout (30000 milliseconds) waiting for the MyService service to
>   connect.

My research indicates that an exit code of 0x80 is often related to desktop heap exhaustion. I ran the dheapmon tool from Microsoft and it suggests that there is no heap pressure:

```
Desktop Heap Information Monitor Tool (Version 8.1.2925.0)
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
-------------------------------------------------------------
  Session ID:    1 Total Desktop: (  4288 KB -    3 desktops)

  WinStation\Desktop            Heap Size(KB)    Used Rate(%)
-------------------------------------------------------------
  WinSta0\Default                    4096             11.5
  WinSta0\Disconnect                   64              4.0
  WinSta0\Winlogon                    128              7.4
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

**A reboot of the server** allows both the Windows Services and the IIS App Pools to function correctly, but only for a short period of time. (Minutes to an hour or so.) This suggests it is some kind of memory pressure (or other cummulative process) that's causing the issue.

I attempted to allow the processes to use the shared desktop heap as described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/831135

But this resulted in the WWW Publishing Service failing to start at all, so I had to roll back the change. Futhermore, the fact I'm not seeing heap pressure makes me think something else is going on anyway.

As a sanity check, I also used SysInternals Process Monitor to see if I was getting any file or registry access denied errors, and I saw none.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but have you tried: installing your app on a different (preferably clean) server? Also, is it possible to run your application under the default accounts (localservice)? If you are able to use localservice, how does your app behave?

Comment: A clean server works fine, but that's not an option for this deployment. There are some compatibility issues with running as localservice or other built in accounts. I can fix those, but would rather fix the root cause than work around in with a special case change.

Comment: If a clean server works, then you need to provide more info on what else is on the machine. We ServerFault readers can only guess what is on there.

Comment: What are you looking for, exactly?